# How to implement a Redis Store for Money/Open-Exchange-Rate-Bank Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, rubygems, currency-exchange-rates

I spent days searching the whole internet and couldn't find any implementation. I, therefore, implemented one and will like to share.

Answer (score 3):

```rb
class RedisRateStore
  INDEX_KEY_SEPARATOR = '_TO_'.freeze
  
  # Using second db of the redis instance
  # because sidekiq uses the first db
  REDIS_DATABASE = 1
  
  # Using Hash to store rates data
  REDIS_STORE_KEY = 'rates'

  def initialize
    conn_url = "#{Rails.application.credentials.redis_server}/#{REDIS_DATABASE}"
    @connection = Redis.new(url: conn_url)
  end

  def add_rate(iso_from, iso_to, rate)
    @connection.hset(REDIS_STORE_KEY, rate_key_for(iso_from, iso_to), rate)
  end

  def get_rate(iso_from, iso_to)
    @connection.hget(REDIS_STORE_KEY, rate_key_for(iso_from, iso_to))
  end

  def each_rate
    rates = @connection.hgetall(REDIS_STORE_KEY)
    return to_enum(:each_rate) unless block_given?

    rates.each do |key, rate|
      iso_from, iso_to = key.split(INDEX_KEY_SEPARATOR)
      yield iso_from, iso_to, rate
    end
  end

  def transaction
    yield
  end

  private

  def rate_key_for(iso_from, iso_to)
    [iso_from, iso_to].join(INDEX_KEY_SEPARATOR).upcase
  end
end
```

```rb
# config/initializers/open-exchange-rate.rb


# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'money/bank/open_exchange_rates_bank'

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  oxr = Money::Bank::OpenExchangeRatesBank.new(RedisRateStore.new)
  oxr.app_id = Rails.application.credentials.oxr_app_id
  oxr.cache = 'db/rates.json'
  oxr.ttl_in_seconds = 3600
  oxr.prettyprint = false

  Money.default_bank = oxr
end
```